# How can I get a subscription feed using the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need YouTube user subscriptions feed ([www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions](http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions))

As I understand it, the most appropriate is `v3/activities?mine=true`, but when using the playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) I always get an empty items array.
By comparison, calling `v3/subscriptions?mine=true` gives me a non-empty array, so I'm assuming it's not an authorization issue.
What is needed for `v3/activities?mine=true` to work correctly?

Perhaps I could use `v3/subscriptions?mine=true` to get a list of channels, then from each channel a list of uploaded videos, merging that into one feed myself. But it would also consume more API usage limit points, especially if the number of channels is large.

There is another way to get the feed of subscriptions?

Comment: What part did you include?  part=snippet&mine=true

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [Subscribing to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

Comment: @linda-lawton-daimto If you about `activities`, I tried all possible `part` values (`contentDetails`, `id`, `snippet`), it doesn't affect the result